# Any Angular directive for handling cookie law compliance?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cookies, angularjs-directive

I have recently decided to start trying to make a site compliant with EU cookie laws. I am using AngularJS as my front end framework. I have been looking at these jquery plugins:

https://silktide.com/tools/cookie-consent/

http://cookiesdirective.com/

However I would prefer to use an angular first solution if that is at all possible. Does anyone know of any angular directive that would be able to handle this?

Comment: AngularJs provides you with the cookie API? what else you need?I dont get it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Easy as that.

```
angular.module('consent', ['ngCookies'])
.directive('consent', function ($cookies) {
  return {
    scope: {},
    template:
      '<div style="position: relative; z-index: 1000">' +
      '<div style="background: #ccc; position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0" ng-hide="consent()">' +
      ' <a href="" ng-click="consent(true)">I\'m cookie consent</a>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>',
    controller: function ($scope) {
      var _consent = $cookies.get('consent');
      $scope.consent = function (consent) {
        if (consent === undefined) {
          return _consent;
        } else if (consent) {
          $cookies.put('consent', true);
          _consent = true;        
        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Add style and animation to taste.

Answer (score -3):

```
AngularJS provides the cookie API
```

Check out the link
[AngularJS Cookie API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

This is how you will be using it

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
}]);
```

Comment: The question was about adding a banner to the website to be compliant with the EU "Cookie Law" (https://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/), i.e. it was not about setting cookies or handling cookies in general. Hence, you did not answer the question.